# Avg,max,min,sum from string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hello i got array of string, and they are durations made by myself in format `H:M:S:MS`

Example strings:

```
0:0:4:410
0:0:1:425
0:0:1:802
0:0:1:509
0:0:1:674
0:0:1:628
0:0:2:76
```

How can i **sum/avg/min/max** values of these items in arraylist?

Arraylist name is `arrayLL`.

I'm new in c# so hope someone will show me how to work with strings.

The function that adds to array is:

```
if (Session["DT"].ToString() != "")
{
    TimeSpan ts = ((DateTime)Session["DT2"]).Subtract((DateTime)Session["DT"]);

    Session["TimeL"] = ts.Hours.ToString() + ":" 
                            + ts.Minutes.ToString() + ":"
                            + ts.Seconds.ToString() + ":" 
                            + ts.Milliseconds.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of these values? Are they durations?

Comment: You need to split the string into components and then convert the sub strings into numeric values. Once you have done this you can average, sum, etc. the values.

Comment: What do they represent, can you give example of what sum .... you want to calculate ?

Comment: How did you get this value? May be that can help how they can be  created back.

Comment: They are durations made by myself in format H:M:S:MS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the numbers represent hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds you can try the following:

```
// Empty list you will populate:
List<int> durationsInMilliseconds = new List<int>();

// Loop through your existing data, and calculate all
// durations into milliseconds:
foreach (string word in yourDurationArray)
{
    string[] values = s.Split(':');
    int hoursAsMilliseconds = Integer.parse(values[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    int minutesAsMilliseconds = Integer.parse(values[1]) * 60 * 1000;
    int secondsAsMilliseconds = Integer.parse(values[2]) * 1000;

    int sumDurationAsMilliseconds = hoursAsMilliseconds + 
                                    minutesAsMilliseconds + 
                                    secondsAsMilliseconds + 
                                    Integer.parse(values[3]);

    durationsInMilliseconds.add(sumDurationAsMilliseconds);
}
```

Now you should have a list of type Integer (`durationsInMilliseconds`) which contains the numbers in a single comparable format. With this, you should be able to do whichever calculations you need.

*(PS: If you need the result in the same format as the original input-data, you will have to add an operation for calculating back from MS into hours, minutes and seconds..)*

Comment: N.B. you can use `TimeSpan.ParseExact(word, "h\\:m\\:s\\:fff", null).TotalMilliseconds` instead of your split and sum.

Comment: Although as Jon Skeet pointed out in another question, `fff` will fail if you only have two digits for the milliseconds, and the alternative `FFF` will not fail but will give the wrong answer. Your split/count is probably the best answer _given how the string is assembled_.

Answer (score 1):

Since i guess they are Durations so i you should do this

```
var enu_ts = yourvariable.OfType<string>().Select(x => 
             TimeSpan.Parse(x, @"h\:m\:s\:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Max

```
var max = enu_ts.Max().ToString();
```

Min

```
var max = enu_ts.Min().ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(string s in dateString)
{
   spanList[i] = TimeSpan.Parse(s);
   total=total.Add(spanList[i++]);
}

Response.Write("Max TimeSpan:"+spanList.Max<TimeSpan>());
Response.Write("Min TimeSpan:" + spanList.Min<TimeSpan>());
Response.Write("Total Sum of TimeSpan:"+total);
```