# TimeSpan.ParseExact giving error

Tags: c#, timespan

I created a `TimeSpan` this way

```
TimeSpan ts = new Timespan();

// Do some addition and subtraction on it
```

Then I am saving it to a file using this

```
string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.MilliSeconds);
```

Various values returned from it are like this

```
0:0:4:410
0:0:1:425
0:0:1:802
0:0:1:509
0:0:1:674
0:0:1:628
0:0:2:76
```

How to convert it back to TimeSpan.

I am using

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact("0:0:4:410", "h:m:s:fff", null);
```

but it is giving me error `Input String is not in correct format.`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: By the way, I'm pretty sure `0:0:2:76` would produce a FormatException anyway, as it doesn't match `h:m:s:fff` (need a leading zero in there!)

Comment: Usually I'd always pair `ToString` and `ParseExact` and use the same format string for both. Not a hack-job with format strings on one end and format-string-based parsing on the other.

Comment: You are trying to improve your answer [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12036070/142637), aren't you? :-)

Comment: @BigYellowCactus: Yes and at the same time improving my C# knowledge.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal So, +1 from me for trying to get better

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does TimeSpan.ParseExact not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719055/why-does-timespan-parseexact-not-work)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you need to parse the colons, basically. I would also suggest using the invariant culture instead of the current thread culture:

```
var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact("0:0:4:410", @"h\:m\:s\:fff",
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx):

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers do not include placeholder separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours, hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these symbols must be included in the custom format string as string literals. For example, "dd.hh:mm" defines a period (.) as the separator between days and hours, and a colon (:) as the separator between hours and minutes.

I would *also* suggest using a format of `h:mm:ss.fff` instead - I believe this would be clearer than your current format. Note that you can use the format directly instead of your currently formatting approach:

```
const string TimeSpanFormat = @"h\:mm\:ss\.fff";

string text = ts.ToString(TimeSpanFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
...
TimeSpan parsed = TimeSpan.ParseExact(text, TimeSpanFormat,
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What about `"0:0:2:76"`? Will this `"@"h\:m\:s\:fff"` suffice or will it give error?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: You could have answered that question yourself by now, coudln't you? (The answer is no, that won't parse. You'd need 076 or 760.)

Comment: @Rawling: Indeed, although with the OP's current way of formatting, that would give the wrong answer (76 milliseconds would then be parsed as 760). Basically the current approach to formatting is a thoroughly bad idea.

Comment: Fair enough, I just noted "doesn't throw an exception" without checking "gives the right answer" :)

Answer (score 1):

you will have to escape the `colons` : when you are doing the parse

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact("0:0:4:410", @"h\:m\:s\:fff", null)
```

> The custom TimeSpan format specifiers do not include placeholder
>   separator symbols, such as the symbols that separate days from hours,
>   hours from minutes, or seconds from fractional seconds. Instead, these
>   symbols must be included in the custom format string as string
>   literals. For example, "dd.hh:mm" defines a period (.) as the
>   separator between days and hours, and a colon (:) as the separator
>   between hours and minutes.

[was bitten some time back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719055/why-does-timespan-parseexact-not-work/11719101#11719101)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = TimeSpan.ParseExact("0:0:4:410", @"h\:m\:s\:fff", null);
```