# How to find lowest and highest time from list?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I have a string list holding time values in this format: `11:25:46.123`, I would like to be able to find highest and lowest time value from this list. How can I do it?

I tried something like this, but I am not sure if it is correct and I don't know what to do next.

```
List<TimeSpan> time = StringList.Select(x => TimeSpan.ParseExact(x, "HH:mm:ss.fff", null)).ToList();
```

EDIT:
I am getting error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format.
```

Comment: So what is your question? How to get max/min? or how to parse a string list? (as that is what you have an error with). I would suggest editing your question and picking one or the other, not both

Comment: At the beggining my question was about min/max values, but now I see that I have error in prasing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am getting error:
>   Input string was not in a correct format.

Your timespan format is not correct. Try this

```
var StringList = new[] { "21:25:46.123" };
List<TimeSpan> time = StringList
                      .Select(x => TimeSpan.ParseExact(x, @"hh\:mm\:ss\.fff", null))
                      .ToList();
var max = time.Max();
var min = time.Min();
```

Comment: @musefan try and see.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Working perfectly!! Thank you. :D

Comment: @musefan Why that format ..check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036972/timespan-parseexact-giving-error/12037072#12037072

Comment: @musefan [Custom format strings for `TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) where introduced in .NET 4.0 (Visual Studio 2010) and are distinct from format strings for `DateTime`. In particular, they don't allow a naked colon, and there is no need to discriminate between `HH` and `hh`.

Comment: Note that Linq methods `.Max()` and `.Min()` will throw if the list is empty (for non-nullable types).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
TimeSpan maxTimeSpan = time.Max();
TimeSpan minTimeSpan = time.Min();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
TimeSpan _maxtime= time.Max(); // For max time
TimeSpan _mintime= time.Min();// For min time
```

also take a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.maxvalue.aspx)

Comment: @musefan just to make sure it always remain easy to understand

Comment: IMO naming the variable meaningful should be more sufficient than comments

Answer (score 2):

Try without using ParseExact

```
List<TimeSpan> times = StringList
    .Select(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x))
    .OrderBy(ts => ts)
    .ToList();
TimeSpan shortest = times.First();
TimeSpan longest = times.Last();
```

Comment: or just TimeSpan.Parse(x)

Comment: ya but TimeSpan.Parse(x) should do the job

Comment: You can even get rid of one lambda (anonymous function with `=>`) because you actually "forward" the parameter list from before the arrow, `x`, unaltered to the named method. What I am trying to say is your line 2 can be written `.Select(TimeSpan.Parse)`.